# Loading external js in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to load external javascript file but I can't use AJAX requests because of *same origin policy*, and I have a code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'test.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

That is ok everywhere (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE9, IE6) but not in IE8, IE7.
 How can I make it work in IE8?

Comment: it depends on where have you inserted this code see second point here http://www.kodeplay.com/2011/04/best-practices-for-ie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the old `document.write('<script language="javascript" src="test.js"><\/script>')`. Also you do not have to append to `head` you can use `body` to.

Comment: p.s. </script>  ->  <\/script> to avoid 'unterminated string literal' error

Answer (score 1):

Try reading up about [JsonP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you had problems in IE, but the following worked in Firefox 4, IE6 and IE9 (i.e. the browsers I had available):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js';
        head.appendChild(script);

        var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (typeof($) !== "undefined") {
                $("<p>it worked!</p>").appendTo(document.body);
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 100);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in fact, your solution is the same as in my question and doesn't work in IE7 and IE8

Comment: uh, no it's not. it waits until the js is loaded and then makes use of it. on my tests, it worked in ie6+.

Comment: yes, you are right. The thing is that I was using 'IE Tester' and it appears to implement IE7 and IE8 not correct, so it's ok with your answer too, but I cannot do multiple submits. So at least I've made an upvote.

Comment: yeah, i've had the same problems with ie tester. i generally just assume that if it works in ie6 and the latest version, it'll work in the in-between ones. it's probably a safe assumption for 99% of cases.